# why every function inside of the component is recreated when a component re-renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning `useCallback` hook and reading an article https://medium.com/@dev_one/how-to-use-usecallback-hook-35dc047aee48 which says:

> when a component re-renders, every function inside of the component is recreated and therefore these functions’ references change between renders

I don't understand why function needs to be re-created? for example:

```
export class SimpleButton extends Component {
   
   handleClick = () => { 
      // ...
   }

   // ...

   render() {
      return (
         <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
           ...
         </button>
      )
   }
}
```

say we call `setState()` in the parent component which makes this `SimpleButton` instance re-render,  react can just call the `render` method on this instance, why react needs to create a new `handleClick` function object and assign it to the current `SimpleButton` instance, what's the benefits of doing that?

Comment: `useCallback` hook can only be used in the function component, but you are using a class-based component. Can you learn it from official documentation? https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback#skipping-re-rendering-of-components

Comment: I'd challenge you to answer "what is the benefit of having every instance of a component share the entirety of it's state?"

Comment: @LinDu yes I understand `useCallback hook can only be used in the function component`, but I would like to know why class based components re-creates function object when re-renders?

Comment: @lch from what I know they don't.  can you please share where you got the information?

Comment: @Hatana  from the quote in my question. Or does the component in the quote mean functional components not class-based components?

Comment: @lch in the whole article they use function components that's why they can use hooks as useCallback so obviously they are speaking about functional components not class-based components

Answer (score 0):

does not make sense to ask what are the benefits of doing this because it happens by default when a component is rendered, but the question is, why doesn't React cache function definitions between re-renders and why not make each function a `useCallback` hook?

actually, we don't want to do this because when the component renders everything is updated so even if the function is recreated it will have access to the new state values and that's fine, therefore, we don't really need to memorize each function, because memorization has its disadvantages too.

### when it is useful?

> `useCallback` potentially improves performance by not having to re-create the function object every time the state changes. This is particularly useful when the function is passed to a child component as it could prevent re-renders caused by changes in the function

This was to answer the question but as mentioned in Lin Du's comment you can only use hooks in a function component context.

Comment: Actually useCallback does not prevent re-creating a function on every render. It just keeps the reference to one of them at a time, it sill gets recreated again and again

Comment: From what I know it does, from what I can see in [this section](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback#parameters) "Otherwise, it will give you the function that you have passed during the current render, and store it in case it can be reused later. React will not call your function." so I don't think the hook is creating another one on every render if it is not needed

Comment: At the end it is just a function useCallback(cb), and you are passing an argument to it as a function. No way to execute the body of the component and not recreate a function again. You are calling useCallback on each render. It decides what to return you, but that does not change the fact that it still accepts arguments, even if it does not use them.

Comment: I got your point but when the hook is called on each rerender. from what I understood it is designed to manage stuff when the dependencies have not changed since the last render and will give you the same function again. so nothing is recreated.  If for example, you put an empty dependency array. in each rerender it will return the same function again and again

Comment: It has nothing to do with the hook. Yes, it returns you the same function again and again. But that does not change the fact that it accepts new function again and again. Even if it does not use it. Think about this: const cb = () => {...}; const cb1 = useCallback(cb, []). This does not prevent cb to be recreated on each render. cb1 is equal to cb only at first render. After that cb gets new reference on each render. cb1 has same value on each render, but cb has new one on each render. The same thing applies for useCallback(()=>{...}, []} The function as argument recreates again and again

Comment: Ah you mean each time you pass a new function to the hook? yes that's right

Comment: Yes, useCallback does not prevent creating new function on each render